# Assign random value to each cell of a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to iterate a column in a panda's DataFrame to assign each cell a unique random value with the `numpy.rand.randint` function.

```
for i in csv_with_id.iteritems():
    csv_with_id['index'] = np.random.randint(1,10000)
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

My problem are the duplicate values on the index column..

I've also tried looping with `iterrows()` and plain `csv_with_id`

Can I get some direction on this?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a minimal example of the original dataframe? Also, where is the 'i' in the next line? for i ... the next row does not have an 'i'. what does the 'index' refer to? a minimal example of the original dataframe could help.

Comment: Thats the original dataframe, im just want to re assigning values on the index column with random ones.

Answer (score 0):

Using `random.choice` function from numpy, you have the possibility to specify `replace=False`, which says that you can't have twice the same values.
This function will give you back a whole vector that you can assign to `df.index`

Example on a dummy dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(8000)})
# get number of rows df values between 0 and 9999 - all distinct
df.index = np.random.choice(range(10000),df.shape[0],replace=False)
```

You can check that the number of distinct elements in `df.index` is the number of rows in `df`:

```
len(df.index.unique())
# 8000
```